# Voicemail calling back 20 seconds later

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to set up voicemail for a Twilio # (Not Twilio Cell)...  And it works, for the most part, except I get called back 20 seconds later with nothing there (Step 5 Below).  I think my issues are in TWIML 1/2 from testing, but I don't know.

1. I'll call in to my Twilo # from my cell.
2. I hit the reject on my cell (Even though my time out is 1, it doesn't give up.).
3. Leave the message
4. Hang up || press button to end
5. **[~20 seconds after step 4] Get blank call back**
6. [10-15 secs after step 5] Get my text / email as expected

**Am I doing something wrong in TWIML 2?**
or
**Is using my cell for orig/term causing problems?**

**Incoming:**

### TWIML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial action="https://-->TWIML 2"
   timeout="1" 
   callerId="{{To}}"       
  >
    <Number>##CELL##</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

### TWIML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Response>
    <Say>
      Please leave a message 
    </Say>
      <Record action="https://TWIML 3"
        method="POST"
        maxLength="120"
        playBeep="false"
        trim="do-not-trim"
        transcribe="true"
        transcribeCallback="https://FUNCTION 1"
      />
    <Say>I did not receive a recording.</Say>
</Response>
```

### TWIML 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Bi</Say>
</Response>
```

### FUNCTION 1

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
var client = context.getTwilioClient();
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: context.MG_KEY, domain:context.MG_DOMAIN});
var async = require('async');

 var sendSMS = function(callback){
   let dataSMS = {
            to: '##CELL##',
          from: event.To,
          body: 'Voicemail from:\n ' + event.From + '\n\nText:\n' + event.TranscriptionText + '\n\n---MSG Recording---\n' + event.RecordingUrl
   };
   client.messages.create(dataSMS).then(function(response){
     console.log('N [T1]: ' + response.status); 
     return callback(null, response);
   }).catch(function(err){
     console.log('T2: ' + err); 
   });
 };

 var sendEmail = function(callback){
   let dataMG = {
            to: '@@TO@@',
          from: '@@FROM@@',
       subject: 'Voicemail: ' + event.From,
          text: event.TranscriptionText + '\n\n--- MSG Recording --->\n' + event.RecordingUrl
     };
   console.log('-------- Sending Mail (Mailgun API)---->' + dataMG.to);
   mailgun.messages().send(dataMG, function (error, body) {
     console.log('N [MB] Mailgun Body :' + body);
     return callback(null, body);
   });
 };

 var waitTime = function(callback){
   setTimeout(function() {
     return callback(200);
   }, 1000);
 };

 var asyncTasks = [sendSMS, sendEmail, waitTime];

 async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(err, result){
   console.log('--------------------------DONE--------------------------' + result[0] + result[1]);
   callback(null, 200);
 });
};
```

---

### Resolved:

So a couple days later and it is **working as expected**, without being phoned back ~20 seconds later.  I don't think I changed anything, but who knows; now I'm having trouble forcing the unexpected behavior to occur :)

**Below** is an **example** of how to set up a **voicemail** system that will **transcribe your message** to a **MMS** including a **link to the original voice message**.  This also includes an email copy, if you had a mailgun account set up.

*There is an extra fee associated with using the transcription service, and you will have to delete the recordings eventually after you no longer want access to the recording.*

If you are to try this out, when clean the code for you situation, the timeout variable in Twiml 1 is how many seconds it will ring for.  Function 1 requires async, but you could write it without when tailoring for you situation.

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.